# style for displaying tooltip box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Not know why tooltip box(class `.show_tooltip`) there is left when mouse enter on `li a`, i want display each tooltip box top same link that mouse is enter on it and if the width and height was more or less it is same style.(i want links put in right) **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AQh6y/3/)**

I want example this (for `how`): what do i do?

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.show_tooltip{
    background-color: #E5F4FE;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: #5A5959 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    color: #0C0C0C;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;*/
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>    
    <div class="show_tooltip">
        put returns between paragraphs
    </div>
        <a href="#">about</a>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>    
    <div class="show_tooltip">
        for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
    </div>
        <a href="#">how</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("li a").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).prev().fadeIn();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
            $('.tooltip').css('bottom', e.pageY - 10);
            $('.tooltip').css('right', e.pageX + 10);
        }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).prev().fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: Note: the br between the li's is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, but not problem from br, this is a example from my originally code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/keepyourweb/ecR2S/2/

Comment: Thanks, you use content tooltip in title i have a content tooltip with html code long in originally code, no a text low(this is just a example of my code), you want guide me without change in my HTML?